# Where to go After Workshop 10.3?

Tags: oracle, upgrade, migrate

This is a historical path of my project

1. Developed App using BEA Weblogic 8.1
2. Oracle acquitted BEA
3. Oracle gave upgrade path from BEA Weblogic 8.1 to Oracle Workshop 10.3

Now the issue is I cannot find any installer for Oracle Workshop 10.3 anymore. I asked Oracle, they said never have it. (Weird though). And last copy of mine was broken.

So, I'm considering moving my Project out of Oracle Workshop 10.3

Question is where to go? Should I choose pure Eclipse or OEPE?

And is there a step by step on how to do it? I will be more comfortable and confident if there is.

Any other alternatives if I'm considering ADF for replacing PageFlow?

Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as still stick to Workshop Framework....there is no way to go anywhere. You stay on Oracle Workshop 10.3

Unless you gonna change everything, take out Workshop out then there are several alternatives.